# Algebraic Variety compact cohomology and singular cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, homology-cohomology

Given an algebraic variety $X$ defined over the complex numbers and its compact cohomology $H^i_c(X)$,
under what conditions it is possible to compute its singular cohomology $H^i(X)$.